# Assigning value to string from base type through constructor using TypeBuilder

Tags: c#, il, typebuilder

I am trying to programmatically define a class with a base class, and a constructor which calls the base constructor. Part of the subclass constructor's job is to initialize a string called name with a value. But no matter what I try name remains null. The base constructor works fine because some arraylists are initialized etc. Typesignature is a string. The field name already exists in the base class.

```
FieldBuilder fbname = tb.DefineField("name", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);

ILGenerator ctor1IL = ctor1.GetILGenerator();
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

//get base constructor
var bc = tb.BaseType.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, bc);  
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, typeSignature);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fbname);
ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The field name already exists in the base class.

This sounds like you already have the field `name` in the base class. If that's the case, what your code does is to create *another* field called `name` in the derived class. You then write to that field, not to the one in the base class.

What you should do is something like:

```
FieldInfo nameField = tb.BaseType.GetField("name");

…

ctor1IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, nameField);
```